# onClick events in nested html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a structure like this:

```
<tr>
 <td onClick="doSomeStuff();">
  <a href="#" onClick="doOtherStuff(1);">1</a>
  <a href="#" onClick="doOtherStuff(2);">1</a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that `doSomeStuff()` always executes, no matter that I am clicking on a `<a href>` element.

How I can fix this?

Comment: When do you want doSomeStuff() to execute?

Comment: When I click on <td> space.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found answer in duplicate post - $('td > a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   })

Comment: Make sure it works on all browsers - I've experienced different behaviour from IE before, which required another way of disabling "bubbling". You can read up on it under _Turning it off_ here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 17):

If you're using plain javascript. Try this

JS

```
function doOtherStuff(event,arg) {
        event.stopPropagation();
}
```

---

HTML

```
<tr>
     <td onClick="doSomeStuff();">
            <a href="#" onClick="doOtherStuff(event,1);">1</a>
            <a href="#" onClick="doOtherStuff(event,2);">1</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what is event inside html?

Answer (score 0):

By using JQuery

```
<tr>
 <td>
    <span class="td">
      welcome
      <a href="#" class="a">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="a">2</a>
    </span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

JQuery Code

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".td",function(){
        alert('td');
    });
    $(document).on("click",".td a",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).on("click",".a",function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```